# set cache control headers for nginx static assets on aws elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions

I've got a node express app running on AWS EB. I'm serving static assets via nginx rather than via the express and want to set the cache control headers.

I think the answer lies in extending the nginx configuration via an ebextension file but the examples I've tried have all ended up in crashing my environment :-(

Please can someone help me with a working version :-)

Here is is the latest ebextension I tried which from everything I have read should work but causes the environment to crash...

`files:
  /etc/nginx/conf.d/02_cache.conf:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
        expires 30d;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
      }`

Comment: Hi can you please try adding double quotes for your filename ? Like this                 "/etc/nginx/conf.d/02_cache.conf"